# Get DN from certificate in ASN.1 format

Tags: c, openssl, asn.1, distinguishedname

I'm trying to get the DN from a certificate in ASN.1/DER format. I have searched OpenSSL but still cannot find the exact function to get the DN.

Does anyone have any experience regarding this or can point me to books or any website?

Comment: Please provide us a minimal, complete and verifiable code. Probably follow the link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @TheApache Sorry. i'm cannot provide any code currently because i still don't know which function that can get DN in ASN.1 format. That why i ask if someone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: Check https://www.gnu.org/software/libtasn1/ which is normally used to parse ASN objects.

Comment: ASN.1 *of what*? An X509 certificate? Just the ASN.1 of a X500 name?

Comment: @vcsjones X509 certificate. I need the DN in ASN.1 format so i can construct PKCS#7 wrapper. As for now i found X509_get_issuer_name(cert) but its just return me string.

Answer (score 0):

I already found a way to do this. I just put here if anyone want to do the same.

```
X509_NAME * cert_entry = X509_get_issuer_name(cert);    
unsigned char buff[100] = {0};
unsigned char * p = buff;
int i = i2d_X509_NAME(cert_entry,&p);

for(int b = 0;b<i;b++)
{       
    printf("%02X ",buff[b]);
}
```

This will print an hexa format.