# Get Distinguised name(DN) from certificate in base64 string

Tags: openssl, certificate

Do you have any idea how to generate the `Distinguished` name(DN) in `base64` string in `OpenSSL` using `Java`?

Or maybe there is a command in `OpenSLL` to get such string?

I need to generate such string to put it in outgoing Edifact file:

Something like here:

```
USC+1F2AB2+4::MIGrMQswCQYDVQQGEwJDWjE5MDcGA1UEAwwwSS5DQSAtIFN0YW5kYXJkIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5LCAwOS8yMDA5MS0wKwYDVQQKDCRQcnZuw60gY2VydGlmaWthxI1uw60gYXV0b3JpdGEsIGEucy4xMjAwBgNVBAsMKUkuQ0EgLSBQcm92aWRlciBvZiBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uIFNlcnZpY2Vz:ZZZ+3'
```

I found a similar problem here: [Get DN from certificate in ASN.1 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634163/get-dn-from-certificate-in-asn-1-format/59154804#59154804)

But my dev team needs a solution in Java.

Comment: You can use bouncycastle java library to get the certificate attributes

Comment: But there is any other option in `openSll` to generate such string?